# Solving linear equations where each matrix element itself is matrix (2D) and each variables are 1D vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-equation

The simple example of the problem is:
[image: $Ax = b$]

In my case:

[image]

Any idea/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are all the 2d's the same shape?  Can they form a 3d array?

Comment: Yes, all the matrix elements are square with same shape. I'm thinking of making a big square matrix out of these 2D matrix elements and then presenting these b elements to single array. And then use linalg.solve to get single X vector which is then separated into each X_i.  Please let me know, if this approach is correct. Or there is some other way to do it around more effectively.

Comment: Simplest would be to stack all of the matrices into one matrix - same with the right hand side `b` vector and solve it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the dimensions conform, A is actually "just" a matrix, even if it is built out of smaller matrices.  Here's a relatively general example showing how the dimensions must go:

```
import numpy
import numpy.linalg

l, m, n, k = 2, 3, 4, 5

# if these are known, obviously just define them here.
A11 = numpy.random.random((l, m))
A12 = numpy.random.random((l, n))
A21 = numpy.random.random((k, m))
A22 = numpy.random.random((k, n))
x1 = numpy.random.random((m,))
x2 = numpy.random.random((n,))

A = numpy.bmat([[A11, A12], 
                [A21, A22]])
x = numpy.concatenate([x1, x2])

b = numpy.linalg.solve(A, x)
```